# Android ListActivity or Activity with ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Salam
my problem is, i have a `ListActivity` rarely in onCreate my app get crashed, when i check it seems setContentView is the problem and i think it cant find my list in xml
the question is which one is better a `ListActivity` or a Activity with ListView?

ListActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@id/activity_welcome_l1"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center"
          android:background="#f5f5f5">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
    <include  layout="@layout/header4" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <ListView
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:background="#00000000"
            >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:orientation="vertical">

    <include  layout="@layout/footer1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> the question is which one is better a ListActivity or a Activity with ListView?

None is better. ListActivity just does some work for you that otherwise you'd have to do yourself, at the price of less customization capabilities. Both approaches are perfectly fine.

To find your problem however, please post the activity code and the logcat output of the crash.